# Etsy API - how to link to seller shop page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, etsy

Been reading the Etsy API documentation for a while and can't find it. Everything tells me to use 'shop_id' or something similar, but I don't have that as a property in my JSON. Is there a way to add the property, or another keyword?

Attempted url is https://www.etsy.com/shop/[shop_id]

Of course, shop_id doesn't work here because I don't have access to it, but the documentation tells me (I think) that I should have it.

Thanks!

See Etsy documentation below:

https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

You have to include "Shop" as a parameter when fetching the search request for the JSON. It's not included automatically. You'll get access to a variety of properties associated to the shop/seller after letting Etsy know you want that particular data.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the shop_id you can use the call **" findAllUserShops ".** This call would return you the list of shops and from this, you can get the shop id that is required for the calls.
https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users/:user_id/shops for getting shop id